# Android Firebase auth: Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.crash and com.google.firebase.auth not found

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication

For my master thesis project I am working on an application for medical diagnostic on Android. I am using Kotlin in Android Studio 3.0 Beta 7. I have implemented a authentication system with Firebase, and every time I run the app in the logcat I get these warnings:

```
DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.

DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
```

I am using the email and password sign-in method. The authentication works just fine, so I don't get the origin of this warnings. My gradle app file has:

```
...
dependencies { 
...
implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.3.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.4.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.4.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.4.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.4.2'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:11.4.2'
...
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Of course I do have Internet permits added in the Manifest. I have tried different approaches I've seen here on SO, but nothing worked:

- I have 12.55 GB of free storage, so it is not about storage space
- Google play services installed are v. 11.5.18
- I have cleared all app data
- Added extra libraries (already listed above)
- Restart Android Studio

Any suggestion? Thanks!

EDIT: I have tested this on 2 devices: Nexus 5 with Android 6.0.1 and Oneplus 5 with 7.1.1

Answer (score 0):

Add the dependencies:

```
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:29.1.0')

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth'
```

I have solved this problem